# "Select all" (Ctrl/Cmd + a) Scope in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change it so that when I'm focusing on a `div` with some text, and I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> the text **inside** the `div` gets selected, without selecting the whole document?

Also: is there a JS/jQuery command to select the text inside a `div`?

Comment: This is not expected behaviour.  When I press Ctrl+A to select all, I expect all to get selected.  As a screen reader user this would drive me insane.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: Selecting Text in an Element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

Comment: You can definitely do that, but don't.

Answer (score -2):

You should use textarea + css to get this feature natively!